# docker-compose run command after container is healthy and before it is available to dependent containers

Tags: docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:

    my-application:
        image: ...
        depends_on:
            my_database:
                condition: healthy

    my_database:
        image: ...
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I want

- `my_database` to start and become healthy
- *after* it is healthy, run an arbitary command in `my_database`'s container
- `my_application` to not run until *both* of those conditions have been met

Is there a way to express this in a docker-compose.yml, without having to modify the images in any way?

Comment: using `wait-for-it.sh` like  `command: 
  bash -c "
  /wait-for-it.sh my_db 
  && ./arbitrary_script
  "`

Answer (score 0):

I guess no Docker just cares about containers literally , not for what they contain , you can use a script in bash inside the second cointainer to wait with `netcat` to hear from host and port when it is ready call your entry point